# How to add methods before trait method call?

Tags: scala, aop, traits

I have a trait

```
trait Trait {
  def method()
}
```

and some implementations

```
class A extends Trait {
  def method() = println("A")
}

class B extends Trait {
  def method() = println("B")
}

class C extends Trait {
  def method() = println("C")
}
```

My goal is to add another method (say, logging) to the trait (not implementations), which will get called right before `method`. What is recommended way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
trait Trait {   
  def innerMethod()   
  def logging()   
  def method = { 
    logging
    innerMethod
  }
}

class A extends Trait {
  def innerMethod() = println("A")
}

class B extends Trait {
  def innerMethod() = println("B")
}
```